# angular perfect scroll bar do not work on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my angular app i am loading data from Json and using prefect-scroll Bar. but scroll bar just display when i scroll not showing on page load. even i used

```
<perfect-scrollbar class="scroller ps-active-y" include-padding='true' wheel-propagation="true" wheel-speed="50" on-scroll="onScroll(scrollTop, scrollHeight)">
```

also use this directive

```
appDirectives.directive('perfectScrollbar', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.perfectScrollbar();

                element.perfectScrollbar('update');

        }
    }
});
```

But no effect any suggestion please.

Comment: But when i add 'E' it is showing error message

Comment: I also get this problem in my project.

Comment: what error you get? try both `restrict: 'EA'`

Answer (score 0):

You currently have your directive restricted to an attribute using `restrict: 'A'`. You should try `<div perfect-scrollbar></div>`. Using `perfect-scrollbar` as an attribute will match what the directive is expecting.

Alternatively, you could change restrict to 'E' which stands for 'Element'.